# What is the difference between session.delete() and session.remove()?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Why there are two methods for deleting the entity in hibernate? Both work in the same style.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-remove).

JPA `EntityManager` interface proposes the `remove` method:

```java
void remove(Object entity);
```

As a JPA provider (see [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#architecture-overview)), Hibernate implements this interface. But, also, hibernate's `Session` interface provides the following methods:

```java
void delete(Object object);

void delete(String entityName, Object object);
```

for the same purpose.

Comment: Case1:. Deleting an entity with JPA
entityManager.remove( person );
Case2:  Deleting an entity with the Hibernate API
session.delete( person ); I found this in documentation. So one method is with JPA and other with entityManager